# How to dynamically select and disable an element in a row in the table when the other element is selected

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, aura, aura-iteration, lightning-components

I am new to Aura and hence was not able to find out the exact way to disable the column.

We are building a table where I need to disable other cells in the row when one of the cell is selected.

The below is the code: (I am truncating the other `<td>` in the table for the brevity. I am only including the `<td>` that we need to manipulate).

```
<table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-no-row-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
            <th class="" scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate">No Hours</div>
            </th>
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.days}" var="day" indexVar="index">
                <th class="" scope="col"><!-- v.days will have Sunday, Monday, Tuesday.....Staurday-->
                    <div class="slds-truncate" style="text-align:center;">{!day}</div>
                </th>
            </aura:iteration>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.timeEntry}" var="timeEntryRow" indexVar="index">
            <aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(timeEntryRow))}">
                <tr class="slds-hint-parent" id="{!'tr'+accountKey}">
                    <aura:if isTrue="{!timeEntryRow.Id != null}">
                        <td>
                            <div class="slds-truncate" style="text-align:center">
                                <ui:inputCheckbox name="{!index+'-FPSA_No_Hours__c'}" aura:id="index"
                                    change="{!c.handleCheckboxChange}" value="{!timeEntryRow.isChecked}" />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="" scope="col" style="width:10px;">
                            <div class="slds-truncate makeRelative" style="text-align:center;padding:0px;">
                                <lightning:input style="width:50px;" aura:id="testSunday" variant="label-hidden"
                                    type="decimal" value="{!timeEntryRow.FPSA_Sunday_Hours__c}" max="24.0" min="0"
                                    oncommit="{!c.hrschange}" name="{!index+'-FPSA_Sunday_Hours__c'}"
                                    onchange="{!c.CantEditHours}" />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <!-- The similar divs will be there for the other days too. The above data is for sunday only and I am not displaying here the other days for brevity.-->
                    </aura:if>
                </tr>
            </aura:if>
        </aura:iteration>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My Goals:

1. How do I disable `sunday cell` and other cells in the row when the `No hours` cell in the row is selected.

Problems I had:

1. I am not able to access the exact element (Ie. sunday cell) from the JS as we cannot use template.querySelector. If I try making the aura:id dynamic for each and every row, I am not able to make the aura:id dynamic. So my question is, how do I access the Sunday cell of THE EXACT ROW where the No Hours is selected from the JS. I need to make this change onChange on `{!c.handleCheckboxChange}`. I am not including `{!c.handleCheckboxChange}` as it does not have any useful stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your iteration object  timeEntry   add one new property  isdisabled.
keep it false while initialization.

on js controller handleCheckboxChange :   if it meets your criteria  make this property  to true for that particular row.
To identify row, if you have sufficient info in your controller then its fine  .otherwise pass any unique field like id  using  data attribute  to identify which row triggered request.

check isdisbaled property of timeentry on html elements you want to disbale/enable dynically.

Comment: Adding the data attribute is fine, but how do I have to query it using JS?

Comment: retrieve  timeEntry object in your method as it will be globally available and iterate over it and modify it.once it is modified and you set it back using component.set.   page will auto rerennder

Comment: Okay. That is regarding the manipulation of timeentry object. But is there any way to get that exact cell using data-* attributes using JS (Like how we do it as template.querySelector in LWC).

Comment: cell is part of a row.on onclik  you already have a value.   you can pass data attribute some unique value then you know it is part of which row.   after that  what do you want to do if not to manipulte original object.   can you share your thought process how you would have done in lwc using queryselector in lwc  if you had to disable some columns of a row conditionally?